# Inline content inside div, without breaking a line

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline

http://jsfiddle.net/FhhP4/

Is it possible to get all this spans in one line, without breaking the 30px height?
I want to get a slider on  if  has content which is widther than 300px.

Content inside line div will be generated and it have to be "float:left" elements

Only css and hmtl

```
    <div id="box">
    <div class="line">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="labelx">Label TXT</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="labelx">Label TXTwergwergwergweg</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    #box {
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    }

    .line {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background:#eee;
    }

    .icon {
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
    background:#000;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `float: left`, set `display: inline-block` to `.icon` and set `overflow: auto` to `#box`.

Code:

```
#box {
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow: auto;
}

.line {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background:#eee;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.icon {
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
    background:#000;
    display: inline-block;
}

.labelx {
    color:#000;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/UXcje/1/

Answer (score 0):

If understand well you need some like this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/FhhP4/13/**

You can use two properties:

```
.line {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

and instead of float:

```
.icon, .labelx  {
  display:inline-block;
}
```